# Extension of a meaning

Tags: singular-vs-plural

For example, if someone's heart is shot with a gun, I can say

> Someone is shot with a gun.

Then, if someone is shot with a gun, and there are people consisting of the person who is shot with a gun, can I roughly say

> They are shot with a gun.

?

'They' indicates the people.

Comment: Is this a metaphor? In what context would you use this sentence?

Comment: If you took a bullet to the heart you would hardly be in a condition to say anything! You would have been shot _in_ the heart _by_ a person _with_ a gun, not 'by a bullet'.

Comment: I think I should make it more clear...

Comment: If you were shot non-fatally, you might say "I've been shot!" I don't know why you think you might use the [royal 'we'](https://grammarist.com/usage/royal-we/)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the fix.  I don't know what "There are people consisting of of the person who is shot by a gun" means.  You can't have "people consisting of a person" it doesn't make sense.  Please clarify.  If two or more people have been shot then "They have been shot" if one man is shot "He has been shot". Perhaps you can tell us what the real context is.  Are you *really* in a place where people are being shot with a gun.  Is this *real*?  If not, please tell us what the real question  is. You might need to delete this and ask a new question.

Comment: Do you mean 'There is a group of people including the person who has been shot'? If so, you would say 'One of them has been shot." You would only use _they_ if all of them had been shot.

Comment: Yes I want your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your heart is shot with a gun you can't say anything, because you are dead.

But, you can't say "We are shot" meaning "I and my heart" because your heart is not a second person, it is part of you.  You can't say "We are shot" meaning "We humans" because the other humans haven't been shot.

The word "We" means either "You and I" or, depending on context "They and I"

However the whole situation is very artificial. Perhaps you can tell us what the real context is. I assume you haven't actually been shot in the heart.

Comment: I fix the question.

Comment: I don't understand the new question.  I will leave this answer until the question is clearer for me.

Comment: I think I was confused with mass nouns...

Comment: mass nouns?  There is nothing in the question about mass (ie uncountable) nouns.

Comment: Who are the *people*? Are we talking about several people, or just the person who was shot? If it's one person you can refer to them as the non-gendered *they*, if that's what you mean.

Comment: If you want a mass noun, e.g. to say what killed a number of people who were shot by one gun or different guns, you can say they were killed (or died) **by gunshot**. "18% of the children killed by gunshot were at home or within 10 meters of their home. " "A near-record number of Americans died by gunshot in 2018"